# How can I enter a param for grails-gsp-link Tag in a gsp Page

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a link via link tag, to a controller where a list function is  coded. I want to execute the list function with a selection, e.g. a Year. I would like the user to have the possibility to enter the Year or any other selection criteria on the gsp-page and to route that user input to the params entry in the link tag. Link tag only offers:

```
<g:link action="list" params="[year: '2018']">myList</g:link>
```

with 2018 hard coded.
I need it as a user entry.

How can I manage it?

Comment: Why don't you use a form?

Answer (score 0):

As Mike W suggested, you should use a form for this.  (If that is entirely not possible, there are alternatives, but form is the best option.)

To provide a simple example:

```
<g:form controller="myController">
    <label for="year">Year:</label>
    <input type="text" id="year" name="year" />
    <g:actionSubmit action="list" value="List" />
</g:form>
```